# In Reactjs how can I do custom message for checkbox. I see there are lot of answers for this issue which works in javascript not in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]

I am still getting select checkbox but I need to show "agree terms" (I do see lot of examples similar to this in javascript but those are not working for me) 
please someone help me with this.

Thanks

Update:

I got the output here is the link which I referred: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/#example1

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to create a stateful component that keeps track of just one piece of state: whether it is checked or not.  You can then derive your message from the checked state inside of your render method.  For instance, you can create a helper method that returns your custom validation message when not checked and returns an empty string when checked.  See code snippet.

```js
const setCustomValidity = isChecked => {
 if (isChecked) {
   return '';
    } else {
     return 'You must agree to the terms';
    }
}

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     checked: false,
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange() {
   this.setState({
     checked: !this.state.checked,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
   const message = setCustomValidity(this.state.checked);
    return (
     <div>
        <p className="customMessage">{message}</p>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          className="checkBox"
          name="checkbox"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Checkbox />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Poosapati, have you had a chance to review my answer yet?  Hoping to know whether it has helped your or not.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Kal, Thanks for the help but I am not looking for this kind of output. Added screenshot for references. It's a default message I want to add custom message saying "Agree Terms" instead select this checkbox.

Comment: I understand! I’m glad you got it figured out.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your solution so others can learn from it.

Here is a solution:

```
        <input
          id="checkers"
          value={this.state.checkered}
          onInvalid={(e) => {
            e.target.setCustomValidity('Please agree to the terms and conditions!');
          }}
          onChange={(e) => {
            **e.target.setCustomValidity(" ");
            setTimeout((e) => {
              document.getElementById('checkers').setCustomValidity("");
            }, 200)**
            this.setState({
              checkered: !this.state.checkered
            });
          }}
          type="checkbox"
          required
          >
        </input>
```

Btw, for this particular case I do not believe you need the code in bold. Though for those who end up having this problem in the future... there is a funny glitch sometimes with the setCustomValidity function wherein even after the validation message fires, the message will keep firing on onInput or onChange of the input field. In my case, e.target.setCustomValidity("") did not actually work (still not sure why), though had to pass a blank space into the a setCustomValidity function to make it work. With this, I then had to reset the setCustomValidity on a time out. Hacky though works like a charm now. If you want to pass in different messages depending on the error, just look at the e.target.validity to see what errors are firing and then return a new message with the setCustomValidity.